# Centered Content Layout w/ Sidebar Link Highlighted to Browser Edge

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm working with a fixed-width, centered, 2-column layout (sidebar and content) with my website's main navigation in the sidebar. When a user hovers over a specific link in the nav or is currently viewing that specific page, I'd like to have a hover/highlighted stage where the nav link has a background color which runs all the way to the edge of the browser.

For example, my layout's sidebar is 200px wide and on the left. My content column is 700px wide and to the right of the sidebar. I've got a "wrapper" div that parents both the sidebar and content divs set at 900px wide and centered by "margin: 0 auto". If a user hovered over a link in the nav, I'd like the link to have a background color that not only sits behind the link, but also continues to the left edge of the browser window, no matter how wide the user has the browser window set at.

Layout example here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pCO7R.gif

Comment: Found this fix: http://ronaldvwilliams.com/archives/432 but disables the horizontal scrollbar. I'd like to try and avoid this solution if possible.

Answer (score 2):

So to do what you wanted using only CSS. Basically set each **li** item to have a large width. Then set the text to be aligned to the right, using text-align. Set the padding (right) to make sure the text isn't kissing the side. Finally use the :hover selector to make each **li** light up (by setting new CSS code) individually.

Note that #nav is the id of the **ul** list. Make sure to make the navigation menu similar to this:

HTML

```
<ul id='nav'>
    <li>Nav Link</li>
    <li>Navy Link</li>
    <li>Nav Links</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
#nav{
    float:left;
}
#nav li{
    width:200px;
    height:2em;
    line-height:2em;
    padding:0px 40px 0px 0px;
    margin:5px 0px 5px 0px;
    text-align:right;
}
#nav li:hover{
    background-color:#000;
    color:#fff;
}
```

EDIT
I forgot to add link styling. Basically inherit the styling/size of the **li**.

```
#nav a{
    width:inherit;
    height:inherit;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
```